# How do I get perl to print n lines following a specific string?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I have a very large file and want to pull out all atom symbols and coordinates for the equilibrium geometry. The desired information is displayed as below:

```
       ***** EQUILIBRIUM GEOMETRY LOCATED *****  
COORDINATES OF ALL ATOMS ARE (ANGS)    
       ATOM CHARGE     X              Y              Z     
-----------------------------------------------------------  
C           6.0   0.8438492825  -2.0554543742   0.8601734285  
C           6.0   1.7887997955  -1.2651150894   0.4121141006  
N           7.0   1.3006136046   0.0934593194   0.2602148346
```

**NOTE:** After the coordinates finish there is a blank line.

I have so-far patched together a code that makes sense to me however it produces  errors and I am not sure why. 
It expects one file after calling on the script, saves each line and changes to $start==1 when it sees the string containing EQUILIBRIUM GEOMETRY which triggers recording of symbols and coordinates. It continues to save lines that contain the coordinate format until it sees a blank line where it finishes recording into $geom.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$num_args = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($num_args != 1) {
   print "\nMust supply GAMESS .log file.\n";
   exit;
}

$file = $ARGV[0];
open FILE, "<", $file;

$start = 0;
$geom="";     
while (<FILE>) {
 $line = $_;
  if ( $line eq "\n" && ($start == 1) ) {
       $start = 0; }

 if ( $start == 1 && $line =~ m/\s+[A-Z]+\s+[0-9\.]+\s+[0-9\.\-]+\s+[0-9\.\-]+\s+[0-9\.\-]+/ ) {
$line =~ s/^\s+//;
@coordinates = split(/\s+/,$line);
$geom=$coordinates[0],$coordinates[3],$coordinates[4],$coordinates[5];

 }
 if ( $line =~ m/\s+\*+ EQUILIBRIUM GEOMETRY LOCATED\s\*+\s+) {
   $geom = "";
   $start = 1;
 }
}

print $geom;
```

Error Message:
`Unrecognized character \xC2; marked by <-- HERE after <-- HERE near column 1 at ./perl-grep line 5.`

Comment: This question would be more accessible if the errors were included

Comment: I see no reason why you wouldn't `use strict` and `use warnings` here. If you do that, and get any error messages/warnings, include them. Maybe someone can help then. Your error is most likely in the first branch of the `if` at `$geom = `.

Comment: `Unrecognized character \xC2; marked by <-- HERE after <-- HERE near     column 1 at ./perl-grep line 5.`

Answer (score 1):

There is an invisible character on line 13

i have created a file with only this line (by cut/paste)
and then add one line above which is my retyping

$geom="";

$geom="";

that looks the same but it is not (the second line is the buggy one)

```
[tmp]=> cat x | perl -ne '$LINE = $_; $HEX = unpack "H*"; print "$HEX $LINE" '
2467656f6d3d22223b0a $geom="";
2467656f6d3d22223be280a80a $geom="";
```

you can see there are some more character when you hexamine the file.
So => just remove completely this single line and retype

By the way, there is another issue in your file, you miss to close the regexp '/'

`if ( $line =~ m/\s+\*+ EQUILIBRIUM GEOMETRY LOCATED\s\*+\s+) {`

but I guess, there are still work to do to finish your script cause i don't see too much the purpose ;)

Answer (score 0):

I copied this over to my Linux box and got the same problem.

Basically, the script is saying that there's an unreadable character at the line:

```
$geom="";
```

I re-typed that line in gedit and it ran file.

Also, there's an unclosed regex at the bottom of your script. I add a "/" to the line that reads:

```
if ( $line =~ m/\s+\*+ EQUILIBRIUM GEOMETRY LOCATED\s\*+\s+) {
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, first and foremost - `strict` and `warnings` are really the first port of call when you're writing a scirpt and having problems. Actually, even before you have problems - switch them on, and adhere to them*.

So as with your code:

- `$geom="";?` - trailing question mark. Should be removed.
- `$num_args = $#ARGV + 1;` - redundant. `scalar @ARGV` has the same result.
- `open FILE, "<", $file;` - 3 arg open is good. Not using lexical filehandles or checking success is bad.
- `$line = $_;` - redundant. Just use `while ( my $line = <FH> ) {` instead.
- `if ( $line =~ m/\s+\*+ EQUILIBRIUM GEOMETRY LOCATED\s\*+\s+)` - broken regex, no trailing `/`.
- `$geom=$coordinates[0],$coordinates[3],$coordinates[4],$coordinates[5];` - doesn't do what you think. You probably want to `join` these or concatenate them.
- `$line eq "\n"` - picks up blank lines, but might be better if you `chomp;` first and `eq ''`.
- `$start` looks like you're trying to do the same thing as the `range` operator. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators
- you overwrite `$geom` as you go. Is that your intention?
- `$line =~ s/^\s+//;` - is redundant given all you do is `split`. `split ' '` does the same thing.
- it's good form to `close` your filehandle after using it. Especially when it's not lexically scoped.

So with that in mind, your code might look bit like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

if ( @ARGV != 1 and not -f $ARGV[0] ) {
    print "\nMust supply GAMESS .log file.\n";
    exit;
}

open( my $input_fh, "<", $ARGV[0] ) or die $!;

my $geom = "";
while ( my $line = <$input_fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    if ( $line =~ m/\s+\*+ EQUILIBRIUM GEOMETRY LOCATED\s\*+\s+/ .. m/^$/ ) {
        if ( $line
            =~ m/\s+[A-Z]+\s+[0-9\.]+\s+[0-9\.\-]+\s+[0-9\.\-]+\s+[0-9\.\-]+/
            )
        {
            my @coordinates = split( ' ', $line );
            $geom = join( "",
                $coordinates[0], $coordinates[3],
                $coordinates[4], $coordinates[5] );

        }
    }
}
close($input_fh);
print $geom;
```

(If you have some sample input, I'll verify it).

* There are occasions you might want to switch them off. If you know what these are and why, then you switch them off. Otherwise just assume they're mandatory.